# Classpath seems correct but JVM still could not find or load main class

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I am relatively new to programming and java and am trying to learn how to create a user-defined package from the command-line. I  get the following: `Error: Could not find or load main class TestPhone`. I've reviewed posts on this type of error including the well-commented post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean).  The post lists 4 steps that the JVM goes through to run a java program:

1. Search for the compiled version of the class.
2. Load the class.
3. Check that the class has a `main` method with signature `static void main(String[])`.
4. Call that method passing it the command line arguments as a `String[]`.

Apparently, my JVM can't find my TestPhone.class for some reason I am yet to figure out. Here's my directory structure:

[image]

My `classpath` is set as follows:

[image]

My classes contain simple codes from Mala Gupta to test accessibility of class variables:

```
package mobile;
class Phone {
    static boolean softKeyboard = true;
}


package mobile;
class TestPhone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Phone.softKeyboard = false;

        Phone p1 = new Phone();
        Phone p2 = new Phone();

        System.out.println(p1.softKeyboard);
        System.out.println(p2.softKeyboard);

        p1.softKeyboard = true;

        System.out.println(p1.softKeyboard);
        System.out.println(p2.softKeyboard);
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't find my classes? Many thanks.

**System specs:**
Java version 1.8.0
Javac 1.8.0
Win 7 on 32-bit OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [java application launcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), `java`, expects the fully qualified name of the class, `mobile.TestPhone`. The `../mobile` directory need not be in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks. I added `../mobile` when all else seem to fail. But it should not be there as you pointed out. `mobile.TestPhone` does it!

Answer (score -1):

You are in the myJavaProject folder in cmd.

Try to go to c:\myJavaProject\mobile  then it should work because your class is in mobile not in 
myJavaProject folder